# Is a 23andMe customer's genomic data used in 230 studies on average?

Tags: medical-science

I read in the article [23andMe Tries to Woo the FDA](http://www.technologyreview.com/news/529006/23andme-tries-to-woo-the-fda/):

> 230:  Average number of studies in which a consenting 23andMe
>   customer's genomic data is used

There is no source to back up this number, which sounds to me as high. Is a consenting 23andMe customer's genomic data is used in 230 studies on average?

I especially wonder what they mean by studies: does a simple SQL query count? I am basically looking for more information around the number of studies of 23andMe customer's genomic data.

Comment: Do you have a context for the word "average"?

Comment: @Sklivvz No the quote I gave is all I have. What clarification are you looking for?